# Sharepoint 2013 (on premise) Information Rights Management configuration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, irm

I have sharepoint 2013 on premise environment. I have installed AD RMS and configure IRM on document library. I want that no user can take print of the document except a user from a specific group.

How can i handle user specific requirement in IRM policy.

Comment: Have a look this. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Apply-Information-Rights-Management-to-a-list-or-library-3bdb5c4e-94fc-4741-b02f-4e7cc3c54aa1?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, where i can mention my custom sharepoint group name which have rights to take print.